# Index must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the error "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list." and am not sure why.

My code is below:

```
'read directory and look for filenames that match pattern and have code elements from xml file

    Dim regElemName As New Regex("^code")
    Dim root = XElement.Load(xmlfile)
    Dim codeElements = root.Element("ApplicationSettings").Elements().Where(Function(xe) regElemName.IsMatch(xe.Name.LocalName)).Select(Function(xe) xe.Value)
    Dim codes = String.Join("|", codeElements.ToArray())
    Dim regFileName As New Regex(String.Format("^\d{5}\-(?<Year>(?:\d{4}))(?<Month>0?[1-9]|12|11|10)(?<Day>[12]\d|0?[1-9]|3[01])\-$", codes))
    Dim files = IO.Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(Function(path) regFileName.IsMatch(IO.Path.GetFileName(path)))

    For Each file As String In files
        Console.WriteLine(file)
    Next
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace for the exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.Format("^\d{5}\-(?<Year>(?:\d{4}))(?<Month>0?[1-9]|12|11|10)(?<Day>[12]\d|0?[1-9]|3[01])\-$", codes)`

You reference `{5}` and `{4}` in your format string, but you're only providing one argument `codes`.  4 and 5 would refer to the 5th and 6th arguments passed to `string.format` respectively.

You receive this error because your format string is expecting you to pass at least 6 arguments (based on the max index that you reference in the format string).